# Skip iterations in enumerated list object (python)

Tags: python, loops, skip

I have the code

```
for iline, line in enumerate(lines):
    ...
    if <condition>:
        <skip 5 iterations>
```

I would like, as you can read, have the for loop skip 5 iterations if the condition is met. I can be sure that, if the condition is met, there are 5 or more objects left in the "lines" object.

lines exists of an array of dictionaries, which have to be looped over in order

Comment: `while` loop can be more efficient in this case i think.

Comment: i need the number of the iteration in the rest of my code, so how would I do it with a while?

Comment: the `continue` command moves the loop to the next iterable

Comment: @kilojoules, that will only skip a single line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
iline = 0
while iline < len(lines):
    line = lines[iline]
    if <condition>:
        place_where_skip_happened = iline
        iline += 5
    iline += 1
```

If you are iterating over a file object you can skip lines using next or make lines an iterator:

```
lines = iter(range(20))

for l in lines:
    if l == 10:
        [next(lines) for _ in range(5)]
    print(l)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
16
17
18
19
```

It really depends on what you are iterating over and what you want to do.

Using your own code with [iter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) and [islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice


it = iter(enumerate(lines))

for iline, line in it:
    if <condition>:
        place_where_skip_happened = iline
        next(islice(it,5 ,5), None)
    print(line)
```

Comment: is this really the most beautiful code? Having to add the iline+=1 at the end of your loop?

Comment: @pidgey What's wrong with that? Why does it need to be sugarified into some idiom? This is short, to the point, and it's clear from the code what the intention is. Nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: as i put in the question, a list of dictionaries

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but the next(lines) won't work over an enumerate(), or will it?

Comment: @pidgey, it will if you call iter on it like I did to range. You can also call `itertools.islice` on the iterator to skip the lines https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: i'll take another look into it, thanks for your advice! :)

Comment: @pidgey, No prob, you're welcome. there is no one answer without knowing the full context of what it is you want to do but this should point you in the right direction

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, thanks :) I just never liked the iline +=1 approach, so I kinda forgot that it was still an option :p

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I see you updated to include the approach in my answer.   But I don't think your version is correct, at least if it was intended to be equivalent to the other two.

Comment: @DSM, I had actually already suggested using islice in a comment long before I added it while I was still figuring out what the OP was trying to do. I presume the OP wants to ignore the next five iterations  which is what my code is doing unless I am missing something?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't think the second argument to `islice` does what you think it does here.  Remember that the iterator itself doesn't know about or care about `iline`.

Answer (score 9):

The standard idiom for doing this is to make an iterator and then use one of the consumer patterns (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the `itertools` docs.)

For example:

```
from itertools import islice

lines = list("abcdefghij")

lit = iter(enumerate(lines))
for iline, line in lit:
    print(iline, line)
    if line == "c":
        # skip 3
        next(islice(lit, 3,3), None)
```

produces

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
6 g
7 h
8 i
9 j
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Using the enumeration index

Similar to the accepted answer… except without using `itertools` (IMHO `islice` doesn't improve readability), plus `enumerate()` already returns an iterator so you don't need the `iter()` at all:

```
lines = [{str(x): x} for x in range(20)]  # dummy data

it = enumerate(lines)
for i, line in it:
    print(line)

    if i == 10:  # condition using enumeration index
        [next(it, None) for _ in range(5)]  # skip 5
```

That last line can optionally be expanded for readability:

```
        for _ in range(5):  # skip 5
            next(it, None)
```

The `None` argument in `next()` avoids an exception if there aren't enough items to skip. (For the original question, it can be omitted as the OP wrote: "I can be sure that, if the condition is met, there are 5 or more objects left in the `lines` object.")

#### Not using the enumeration index

If the skip condition isn't based on the enumeration index, simply treat the list as a FIFO queue and consume from it using `pop()`:

```
lines = [{str(x): x} for x in range(20)]  # dummy data

while lines:
    line = lines.pop(0)  # get first item
    print(line)

    if <condition>:  # some other kind of condition
        [lines.pop(0) for _ in range(5)]  # skip 5
```

As before, that last line can optionally be expanded for readability:

```
        for _ in range(5):  # skip 5
            lines.pop(0)
```

(For large lists, use `collections.deque` for performance.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a functional programming style with recursion, first by putting the necessary parts of your `for` loop into a function:

```
def my_function(iline, line, rest_of_lines, **other_args):
    do_some_side_effects(iline, line, **other_args)

    if rest_of_lines == []:
        return <some base case>

    increment = 5 if <condition> else 1
    return my_function(iline+increment, 
                       rest_of_lines[increment-1], 
                       rest_of_lines[increment:],
                       **other_args)
```

Optionally, if it doesn't need to return anything, you can just adjust those lines of code to be function calls, and the return result will be `None`.

Then some place you actually call it:

```
other_args = get_other_args(...)

my_function(0, lines[0], lines[1:], **other_args)
```

If you need the function to return something different for each index, then I would suggest modifying this slightly to account for the output data structure you want. In that case, you might want to pass the inner result of `do_some_side_effects` back into the recursive function call so it can build up the result.

```
def my_function(iline, line, rest_of_lines, output, **other_args):
    some_value = do_some_side_effects(iline, line, **other_args)

    new_output = put_value_in_output(some_value, output)
    # could be as simple as appending to a list/inserting to a dict
    # or as complicated as you want.

    if rest_of_lines == []:
        return new_output

    increment = 5 if <condition> else 1
    return my_function(iline+increment, 
                       rest_of_lines[increment-1], 
                       rest_of_lines[increment:],
                       new_output,
                       **other_args)
```

Then to call

```
other_args = get_other_args(...)

empty_output = get_initial_data_structure(...)

full_output = my_function(0, lines[0], lines[1:], empty_output, **other_args)
```

Note that in Python, because of the way most of the basic data structures are implemented, this programming style is not going to gain you efficiency, and in the context of other object oriented code it may even be bad style to complicate things beyond the simple `while` solution.

My advice: use the `while` loop, though I would tend to structure my projects and APIs so that using a recursive functional approach will still be efficient and readable. I would also try not to allow side effects inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Padraic Cunningham states, you can do this with a while loop, you can also use a dictionary to replace the if-statement:

```
iline = 0
skip = {True:5, False:1}

while iline > len(lines):
    line = lines[iline]
    ...
    iline += skip[condition]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an external flag and set it when condition is met and check it in the beginning of cycle:

```
ignore = 0
for iline, line in enumerate(lines):
    if ignore > 0:
        ignore -= 1
        continue

    print(iline, line)

    if iline == 5:
        ignore = 5
```

Or explicitly extract 5 elements from enumeration:

```
enum_lines = enumerate(lines)
for iline, line in enum_lines:
    print(iline, line)

    if iline == 5:
        for _, _ in zip(range(5), enum_lines):
            pass
```

I personally prefer first approach, but second one looks more Pythonic.